# How to set content type to open pdf in new tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, content-type

I am using javascript. I have a pdf file stored on server which i need to open in new tab using javascript. I have tried the below code

```
function openPDF() {
  var urlToPdfFile = "http://www.demosite.com/pdf/demo.pdf"; //something like this
  window.open(urlToPdfFile);
}
```

But I keep getting error like below

```
Unknown content type requested.

URL: '/pdf/demo.pdf'.

Requested extension: '.pdf'.
```

This because I see the content-type is html in the request.

how can I open PDF in new tab using javascript, by providing the content-type...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it works:

```
function openPDF(urlToPdfFile) {
  window.open(urlToPdfFile, 'pdf');
}

openPDF('http://www.demosite.com/pdf/demo.pdf');
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm trying to understand why this would work. I thought the problem was with the MIME type from the server side. According to MDN, I thought the second parameter was just a window name. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @CoursesWeb I am facing the same problem,it didnt work

Comment: I tested with Mozilla Firefox and it worked, it opened a new window with the address of the pdf file. Not know way in] your case not work.

Comment: I am currently facing some issue, on server setup i guess. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @CoursesWeb It worked. Thanks. Even without using 'pdf'. Some server issue.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer since it's incorrect. AFAIK there is no way to override the accepted mime type.

Comment: the second parameter of window.open is windowName, it has nothing to do with mime type.